# Finding substrings of string such that product of the length of the substring with its number of occurrences is maximized

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures

I was thinking of the following problem:
Given a string S, let the length of the i<sup>th</sup> substring be l<sub>i</sub> and number of occurrences of the i<sup>th</sup> substring be o<sub>i</sub>. Print the substring such that l<sub>i</sub>*o<sub>i</sub> is maximized.

I have O(n<sup>3</sup>) solution (brute force) for this problem where I am generating all the substrings and finding the substring with maximum value. My code for the same is as follows:

```
public static void solve(String S) {
    long max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    String res = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < S.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= S.length() - i; j++) {
            String s = S.substring(i, i + j);
            int o = countOccurrences(S, s);
            long p = (long) o * (long) s.length();
            if (max < p) {
                max = p;
                res = s;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(res);
}
```

where countOccurrences() method takes O(n) time. I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to achieve this.

Comment: Can the occurrences, overlap each other? Eg. for S = 'ababa', is the answer = 3 * 2 = 6?

Comment: Yes. The occurrences can overlap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a linear-time algorithm:

1. Build a suffix tree on the input string.  This takes O(n) time and space.
2. Traverse the suffix tree in postorder DFS, calculating the number of descendants for each node by summing the values of its children.  As soon as this quantity is known for a node, multiply it with its string length (which is the sum of the length of all edges from the root) and update the best-so-far total if necessary.  This also takes O(n) time.

The key points are that

- A suffix tree contains only a linear number of internal nodes, and
- **Any substring that does not correspond to an internal node cannot produce a maximal score.**  This is because as you trace it from the suffix tree root it must reach "partway down" some edge -- but you can always extend it further without reducing the number of occurrences (which is the number of descendants), and thus increase the score, by continuing on down to the next node.

It might also be possible to do this using suffix arrays instead of suffix trees, in which case it's likely to require a constant factor less memory, but add a logarithmic factor to the running time.

Comment: Why suffix arrays should add logarithmic factor to the running time? There are algorithms constructing SA in linear time...

Comment: @EvgenyKluev: I'm aware of linear-time algorithms for SA construction, but I'm uncertain about the time needed for a DFS.  Maybe this can also be done in linear time using an LCA table?  Please suggest your approach, or edit my answer directly.

Comment: There is a known way to mimic DFS in SA by preprocessing LCA array for range minimum queries then traversing array with pairs of pointers. Linear time preprocessing and constant time query RMQ is possible but not easy to implement.

Comment: There is a nice paper ["Replacing suffix trees with enhanced suffix arrays"](http://www.vmatch.de/AboKurOhl2004.pdf) which explains how to perform DFS and many other tasks in SA.

Answer (score 1):

An idea : You could shorten a bit the algorithm by creating an occurence list. This way before running `countOccurences` you would check if it hasn't been already counted for that occurence and you wouldn't run `countOccurences` again for that same occurence.

This is a first optimization, there should be other ones but it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you can calculate the maximum available 'score' with what you have left, and thus avoid checking for substrings beyond a certain point. I'd guess it still scales badly, but it artificially reduces your 'n' value.

For example, if you have a string of length 10, and you manage to get a 3 character substring twice in the first 3 characters (ie 0-2, 3-5), then you can say max = 6. At that point, once you move beyond i=4, you can't score more than 6, so you can stop?

Answer (score 0):

Improved algorithm will be as follows :- (Psuedo code)

```
int max = 0;

 for(int i=0;i<str.length;) {

   occurences = get_index(str[i]);

   for(int j=i+1;j<str.length;j++) {

      if(occurences.size()==0)
         break;

      for(int k=0;k<occurences.size();k++) {

           int next_ind = occurrences[k]+j-i;

           if(next_ind==length||str[next_ind]!=str[j]) {
               delete(occurences[k]);
           }
       }

       int score = ocurrences.size()*(j-i+1);

       if(max<score)
         score = max; 
   } 

 }
```

**Time Complexity :-**

Ideally the occurrences of the substring should decrease like `n,n/2,n/3....` at max so hence the algorithm is `n*n*(1+1/2+1/3...) = O(n^2*logn) as (1+1/2+1/3...1/n) => logn`. The occurence deletion can be done easily in `O(1)` using linked list.